# Fullscreen Slider assistance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

recently, I have found this awesome fullscreen slideshow located [HERE](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/06/05/fullscreen-slit-slider-with-jquery-and-css3/)

I wanted to test some things on the first index of that link (so the first demo); I therefore downloaded the source and deleted the index2.html and started working with the first index.

I then went on wanting to write some stuff with the h1 tag at the end of the div, however whatever I did, my text did not come up, it was just the fullscreen slideshow.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Do you want to share any code or do we just guess?

Comment: I have included the source codes I am using where I have written 'HERE' above.

Comment: Add related code YOU have tried to your question, not a link to codrops.

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dt6f3zrz/   though I am unsure why the slideshow effect is not showing. It should be just like the one that you visit on that webpage located above.

Comment: You didn't have jQuery enabled and you initialized your slideshow before the specific demo javascript was loaded. Here is a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/macsupport/dt6f3zrz/11/). I still have no idea what you want to do with the h1 tag

Comment: Hey! Don't worry, I believe it is now fixed, I thank you dearly, if I encounter any problems, if you do not mind, I'll comment back on here.